# Loading XML layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, loading

I have a problem loading previously created layout. I would like to load it and change text on buttons inside, then show it to the user. It will be quiz question and I have to show it many times during one activity. I don't want to create new class for my layout.

What do I have to use? I read something about Inflate class, but I think it is used only to create new classes. I tried `setContentView()` method, but app stops when method doing this load starts:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.CapitalQuestionLayout);
setContentView((View) layout);
```

Can someone give some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the layout field not the id field, when you call from the R class, like so :

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.CapitalQuestionLayout);
setContentView((View) layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a "Quiz" app your basic requirement is:

1. a layout which has a `TextView` for Question and 4 `Buttons` for options.
2. a set of questions; pretty obvious :-).

You can create a Custom Class - Questions that will hold Text for a question and its associated options (as Strings).

Now, whenever you want to display a new question with different text for buttons just do the following:

1. If user clicks on right answer then display a `Right-Answer-Activity` to the user (that has a `next-question-Button`).
2. When user clicks on `next-question-button` you can display `Question-Activity` and populate the layout-views with a randomly picked question-object's attributes (i.e. Question's text and options' text).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Quiz will have only two combinations: match country with capital and country with continent.

I planned it this way, that countries (about 150) are in SQLite and activity reads them while entering quiz activity from menu. After reading it randoms question and show layout (load, change button labels). Activity is also a listener. When user choose correct answer, it shows Toast and make new question, if it's wrong it shows dialog and then new question.

I just have issue how to load view prepared in XML, change data and show it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common in Android apps. Do your fields/buttons have an id? For the parent activity, you mostly do

```
Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.the_id_to_the_button_you_want_to_change);
```

This allows you to do things like

```
someButton.setText("What is the ultimate answer to life, the universe, and everything?");
```

Look up the Andorid documentation if you want to do other things like set the color. If you have a viewgroup of some sort (RelativeLayout / LinearLayout / etc), you can specify that specific one

```
Button someButton = (Button)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.awesomely_named_button_identifier);
```

The above someOtherButton is used more often with inflated viewGroups

Comment: Well, I missed to say I have to place this layout instead of the first shown. There is a loading circle and then after preparing Question i have to load layout and swap it with the first one.